# Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, mpdf

I am using mpdf 8.1 with yii2 and php version is 5.6.40 for pdf report download. It's works fine in local environment. But class mpdf is not found in live server with same php version.

mpdf library is uploaded in vendor directory and path is vendor/mpdf/mpdf. And I'm using like these,

```
use Mpdf\Mpdf;
class ReportController extends Controller
{
    public function actionPdfUsageReport()
    {
          $content = "<div>Hello</div>";
          $marginValue = PdfSettings::GetTabularReportMarginSetting();
          $pdf = new Mpdf($marginValue);
          $stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . "/css/mpdfstyletables.css");
          $pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
          $pdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
          $pdf->SetTitle("Title");
          $pdf->SetAuthor("Author.");
          $pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
          $pdf->WriteHTML($content);
          return $pdf->Output('Usage Summary.pdf', 'I');
    }
}
```

System information
Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.40

Comment: you need to run the `composer update` on live server to download the compoer package for the MPDF library

Comment: where is placed the mdpf extension/library ??

Comment: in vendor directory, like as all extension/library.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam just did that, no success.

Comment: if you installed via composer it should be installed at the path `vendor/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php` the namespace is correct

Answer (score 2):

mpdf library was uploaded manually, so I clean that and reinstalled mpdf library through composer. works fine now. Thanks to @MuhammadOmerAslam

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it has happened that I ran the command "composer require mpdf/mpdf" in the wrong directory. It's happened before. Checking what I did showed me the error. I made sure to run it again in the Cake directory and then the error disappeared.